# Responsive Images in a Responsive Container?

Tags: image, html, css

How do I get this Responsive Image, or what is supposed to be, to fit into the parent it is nested in?

I have applied the proper CSS, I have not defined any width or height in the HTML. Here is my CSS.

```
.header {
    height: 25%;
    width: 95%;
    padding: 2.5%;
    background: #fff;
}
.header img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You can view the issue here:
http://www.client.noxinnovations.com/jensenblair/

The big circle image? That's supposed to be Responsive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may be missing something here, but setting:

```
height:100%;
```

For the image works for me...

Comment: That's awesome @Alan. Thank you. But why? I am curious.

Comment: The 100% is saying that the height of the image should be 100% of the height of the container. As the container is defined as a percentage of the height of the viewport, it scales, therefore so does the image.

Comment: You can also add width:auto; to get  the image in its approximate ratio

Answer (score 2):

You need only to change max-width to width, like this:

```
.header img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if you aplly

> display:flex;

to the parent all of the block-type elements they will have a max-width of the parent element.